# AWStats: page views by country (locale)

Tags: page-views, awstats

I know there is a way to see who (who meaning which countries, not specific IP addresses) views your website, and how many pages they view under "Locales"; however, I am trying to understand who views a specific page on my website and how often they view it. Is there a way to see page views by country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Google analytics. You can define custom reports like this:

- Metrics: Pageviews, any other metric that you are cerious about :P
- Dimension: Page

And then apply.
Then add a secondary dimension "Country". You will be able to see how many times a page is viewed in each locacle.